# Error in `mutate()`: `propensity_gam` must be size 3152 or 1, not 6221

Tags: r

I'm working on propensity score and looking at the weight

```
df_all <- df_all %>%
  group_by(clozapine.or.not) %>%
  mutate(propensity_gam = predict(mod, type = "response"),
         weight_gam = 1 / propensity_gam * death_yn + 
           1 / (1 - propensity_gam) * (1 - death_yn)
         )
```

However, the output is

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `propensity_gam = predict(mod, type =
  "response")`.
x `propensity_gam` must be size 3152 or 1, not 6221.
i The error occurred in group 1: clozapine.or.not = 1.
```

I am new to R, could you please help me with this issue? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: to help you you need to provide a dataframe `df_all`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue has to do with the dimension of your data frame, `df_all`, which has 3152 rows after grouping.

On the other hand, `predict(mod, type = "response")` has 6221 values, hence the error.

I do not know what your data actually looks like, so I'm just guessing. But I would try resolving the issue by reversing the order. i.e., you first mutate a new column with `predict(mod, type = "response")`, and then group by the variable `clozapine.or.not`.